# "1 сезон 2 эпизод" или "2 эпизод 1 сезон"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть ли возможность с помощью `preg_match` подобное создать в одном запросе?
Знаю что можно по отдельности искать, но очень хотелось бы узнать возможно ли подобное?

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать со строками “1 сезон 2 эпизод” или “2 эпизод 1 сезон”?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

На js так, в php регулярка та же:

```
["1 сезон 2 эпизод", "2 эпизод 1 сезон"]
.map(s => s.match(/^(?=.*(\d+)\s*сезон)(?=.*(\d+)\s*эпизод)/i)) == ',1,2,,1,2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parrent='/(1\sсезон\s2\sэпизод|2\sэпизод\s1\sсезон)/';
//где \s -пробел, | - или

if (preg_match($parrent, $text)){
    echo 'Вхождение найдено';
}
```

Подробнее почитать про синтаксис регулярных выражений Вы можете [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) или [здесь](http://regexpstudio.com/ru/TRegExpr/Help/regexp_syntax.html)

Comment: Ну очень бесполезный ответ мимо вопроса...

Comment: @Qwertiy почему?

Comment: Я понял, что он хочет достать номера эпизода и сезона независимо от того, в каком порядке они перечислены, а не саму строку. Это раз. Далее, зачем ты захардкодил `1` и `2` в регулярке? И, наконец, `.*?` для чего там?

Comment: @Qwertiy **1** preg_match - как бы ищет, а что ищет юзер непонятно(мы подумали про строку). **2** - какое условие, таков ответ, **3** - согласны, не в тему(ночь уже, поменяли). по поводу хардкода - пусть юзер напишет, что ему конкретно нужно, поменяем регулярку.